# How to send JSON object list to light box?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, lightbox

In MVC 4 application I want when click a link, to show some related Products list in lightbox. I have method returns products I need:

```
 public ActionResult GetRelatedProducts(int id)
    {
       var realProducts = GetRelatedProducts(id);
       List<object> productsObjectList = new List<object>();
       foreach (var item in realProducts)
       {
             productsObjectList .Add(new
             {
                 id = item.Id,
                 fullname = item.Name
             });
       }
       return Json(productsObjectList , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

HTML is:

```
<a class="show" id="show">Show</a>

<div  id="productBox" style="display: none;">
    // Product list will get here
</div>
```

And script:

```
     $('#show').click(function (e) {
     url = '@Url.Action("GetRelatedProducts", "Product")';
     var data = { id: '@Model.Id' };
     $.post(url, data, function (result) {
           $('#productBox').lightbox_me({
           onLoad: function () {

             //How to send returned product list to light box, to show them by foreach loop

           }
       });
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

How can I send product list to  `productBox` to show products?

Comment: Are you sure you need to return json, you can make simple partial view and render list there and return plain html and than initialize light box passing html to it.

Comment: its all the same to me. It can be partial view. But I could not understand well. will Partial view return plain html with Product names?

Comment: Yes it should, but you will not put that inside lightbox_me load function, you should add result to #productBox. And then call $('#productBox').lightbox_me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code:

```
$('#show').click(function (e) {
     url = '@Url.Action("GetRelatedProducts", "Product")';
     var data = { id: '@Model.Id' };
     $.post(url, data, function (result) { // <- "result" will contain array
       $('#productBox').lightbox_me({
           onLoad: function () { ... }
       });
       e.preventDefault(); // <- this must prevent "a" tag, put it outside
     });
});
```

You could use your list on client side like this:

```
$.post(url, data, function (result) {
    var list = '<ul>';
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        list += '<li>' + result[i].fullname + '</li>';
    }
    list += '</ul>';
    $('#productBox').html(list).lightbox_me();
});
```

OR as **Vladimir Bozic** wrote, just use `PartialViewResult`, from controller return `PartialView`, it is like normal view, but without layout, just html block and you can use it like:

```
$.post(url, data, function (result) {
    $('#productBox').html(result).lightbox_me();
});
```

Comment: Did not see your answer, when i posted comment that is what i meant +1 from me :)